# Finding array partition where max(left) < min(right) - possible in O(N) time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've just tried a coding challenge to write a function that returns the length of the shortest possible left partition of an array of numbers, all of whose elements are less than all of the elements in the corresponding right partition.

The scenario given was finding the divide between "winter" and "summer" given a variable number of monthly temperature readings, with the rule that all winter temperatures are lower than all summer temperatures.  We can assume that there is at least one correct partition, and the goal is to get the shortest winter.

Is it possible to do this in O(N) time, i.e. the processing time increases linearly with the number of temperature readings?  The fastest solution I can come up with has to find the minimum summer temperature (lowest number in the right partition) for every maximum winter temperature considered:

```
function shortestWinterLength temps
    maxWinterTemp = -Infinity

    for i from 0 til temps.length
        minSummerTemp = Infinity

        for j from i + 1 til temps.length
            minSummerTemp = Math.min minSummerTemp, temps[j]

        maxWinterTemp = Math.max maxWinterTemp, temps[i]

        if maxWinterTemp < minSummerTemp
            return i + 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach mentioned in the question for computing min(temps[i+1], ... temps[n]) is inefficient because many similar comparisons are made for different *i* values.

Instead, all the "min" values can be obtained by performing a single pass through the array, but by **iterating from right to left**.

Thus, it would be necessary to perform an initial pass from right to left which would store the minimum reached so far in an auxiliary array. Afterwards, you can use the same loop over `i` from the current solution, but the inner loop over `j` would be replaced by simply retrieving the "min" from the auxiliary array just computed.

This solution has O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the C++ code for O(n) Time and O(1) Space Complexity.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {

        int leftMax = A[0];     //  Max temperature during winter
        int maximum = A[0];     //  Max temperature during the year
        int position = 1;       //  Possible solution

        int n = A.size();

        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (A[i] < leftMax) {
                position = i+1;      // got a new lower value
                leftMax = maximum;
            } else if (A[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = A[i];
            }
        }        
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: This will fail for array of [-5,-5,-5,-42,6,12, -50]. You are meant to return the position the moment the current day's temperature exceeds leftMax thus breaking the loop and not after the for loop.

Comment: @Willower, Looks like you didn't read the question carefully. it said, "We can assume that there is at least one correct partition, and the goal is to get the shortest winter."

Comment: I did actually and your quote is exactly what led to my thought. Take the sample array I gave for instance, using your method would return 7 days of winter which 
1. Is the whole array and not a partition of it, meaning there's no summer.
2. Is longer that what it would have returned if we broke the loop when we encountered a "summer" temperature hence not the shortest winter.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `O(n)` solution is possible but with additional memory.

Let's fill the array `minR` where `minR[i] = min(A[i], ..., A[n])`.

The values of this array can be computed in `O(n)`. We just iterate through the initial array in reverse order and calculate the minimum value among last array elements:

```
minR[n-1] = a[n-1]
for i from n-2 downto 0 
    minR[i] = min(minR[i+1], A[i])
```

Then all you need is to iterate through the array calculating the maximum value among first `i` array elements and comparing this value with `minR[i+1]`:

```
maxL = 0
for i from 0 to n-2
    maxL = max(maxL, A[i])
    if maxL < minR[i+1] then 
        outputResult(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Code :

```
def shortestWinterLength(listofTemperatures):

    if len(listofTemperatures) == 0 :
        return 0

    length = len(listofTemperatures)
    winter_high = listofTemperatures[0]
    overall_high = listofTemperatures[0]
    winter_length = 0

    # Get max in the left array  
    for temperature in listofTemperatures:
        if temperature <= winter_high : 
            winter_high = overall_high
        elif temperature > overall_high :
            overall_high = temperature

    # count all the values which are less than max in left array
    for temperature in listofTemperatures :
        if temperature <= winter_high : 
            winter_length += 1

    # total length of the left array
    return winter_length
```

Time Complexity - O(n) 
Space Complexity - O(1)

Comment: You can also just store the index of winter_high each time you update it. If you do that, then you don't need the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Here I'm sharing my two solutions (in Java) for this Codility problem of "Winter Summer". I used the second one and scored 100%:**

```
/**
 * Time Complexity: O(n) Space Complexity: O(n)
 * <p>
 * This version uses an auxiliary array to calculate all the possible summer mins.It is good enough but it is not so memory-efficient and that might be crucial as the size of the input size increases, so I went ahead and tried an in-place solution, which is the one I am exhibiting as "the" solution at {@link
 * #shortestWinterLengthOnePass(int[])} (see below)
 */
private static int shortestWinterLengthAuxArray(int[] temperatures) {
    int n = temperatures.length;

    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }
    int[] summerMin = calculateAllPossibleMinimums(temperatures);

    int winterMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        winterMax = Math.max(temperatures[i], winterMax);

        if (winterMax < summerMin[i + 1]) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

/**
 * Dynamic Programming: calculate all possible minimums from every position, in order to avoid double iterations on
 * the main algorithm, avoiding a time complexity of O(n^2).
 *
 * @param temperatures the array of temperatures to scan
 *
 * @return an array that, on its "i" position, will hold the minimums from temperatures[i]...temperatures[n-1]
 */
private static int[] calculateAllPossibleMinimums(int[] temperatures) {
    int n = temperatures.length;
    int[] summerMin = new int[n]; // auxiliary array. position "i" will hold the minimums from i...n-1
    summerMin[n - 1] = temperatures[n - 1];

    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        summerMin[i] = Math.min(temperatures[i], summerMin[i + 1]);
    }
    return summerMin;
}
```

**And now, my preferred solution:**

```
/**
 * This is my second stab at the problem, that iterates the input array only once. It has:
 * <p>
 * Time Complexity: O(n) Space Complexity: O(1)
 */
private static int shortestWinterLengthOnePass(int[] temperatures) {
    int n = temperatures.length;

    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int winterHighest = temperatures[0];
    int currentOverallHighest = temperatures[0];
    int winterLength = n;

    // Establish the max temperature in the winter partition so that winterHighest < "the lowest of summer"
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int current = temperatures[i];

        if (current <= winterHighest) {
            // found something lower than our current highest, it must be included in the "winter" (left) partition
            winterHighest = currentOverallHighest;
            winterLength = i + 1;   // keep track of the (last) position where the above realization happened
        } else if (current > currentOverallHighest) {
            currentOverallHighest = current;
        }
    }
    return winterLength;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in C:

```
int arr[] = { -5, -5, -5, -42,  6 , 120 };

int  winter_high[6] =  { NULL };
int  overall_high[6] = { NULL };

int j,k; 

  winter_high[0] = arr[0];
  overall_high[0] = arr[0];

for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] <= winter_high[j])
    {
        winter_high[j] = arr[i];
        j++;
    }


    else if (arr[i] > overall_high[k])
    {
        overall_high[k] = arr[i];
        k++;
    }
}

printf("The length of the winter sub array: %d ", j);
printf("The length of the summer sub array: %d ", k);
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  See https://gist.github.com/user896724/042adc37e22a82d81d240bc5fd3b4890 which outputs: The length of the winter sub array: 1
The length of the summer sub array: 5

Answer (score 0):

Java program to find the shortest winter with O(n) time complexity:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A = {4, 3, 2, 5, 8, 6, 7};
    //int[] A = {-3, -2, 3, 4, 6};
    int n = A.length; 
    System.out.println(FindElement(A, n));

}

static int FindElement(int[] A, int n) 
{ 
    // Create an array 'SE[]' that will  
    // store smaller element on right side. 
    int[] SE = new int[n]; 

    // Create an another array 'GE[]' that  
    // will store greatest element on left side. 
    int[] GE = new int[n]; 

    // initialize first and last index of SE[], GE[] 
    GE[0] = A[0]; 
    SE[n - 1] = A[n - 1]; 

    // store greatest element from left to right 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)  
    { 
        if (GE[i - 1] < A[i]) 
            GE[i] = A[i]; 
        else
            GE[i] = GE[i - 1]; 
    } 

    // store smallest element from right to left 
    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)  
    { 
        if (A[i] < SE[i + 1]) 
            SE[i] = A[i]; 
        else
            SE[i] = SE[i + 1]; 
    } 

    // Now find a number which is greater then all 
    // elements at it's left and smaller the all 
    // then elements to it's right 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)  
    { 
        if (j == 0) {
            if (A[j] < SE[j + 1])
            return j+1;
        } else if(j == n - 1) {
            if(A[j] > GE[j - 1]) {
                return j;
            }
        } else if(GE[j - 1] < SE[j] && A[j] > GE[j - 1]) {
            return j;
        }           

    } 

    return -1; 
}
```